# Polynomial in an endomorphism $u$ : justification?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In my course we defined the value of a polynomial $P=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_kX^k$ in the endomorphism $u$ of a vector space E:
$$
P(u)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_ku^k=\alpha_0Id_E+\alpha_1u+\cdots
+\alpha_nu^n
$$

Is it really a definition ?

I feel there is a justification of this definition ? How can we evaluate a polynomial in an endomorphism?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, the set of endomorphisms of a [module over a ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29) $R$ itself forms an algebra over $R$  with the operations of pointwise addition ($(f+g)x = fx+gx$) and composition ($(fg)x = f(gx)$), and multiplication by elements of $R$ given by $(rf)x = r\cdot fx$.

So given an arbitrary endomorphism $u$ of a vector space $E$ (which is just a module over a field), and a polynomial $P$, then we can make sense of $P(u)$ as an well-defined element of the endomorphism ring, since we have a sensible notion of multiplying endomorphisms by elements of our field, multiplying (composing) endomorphisms, and adding them.

In the case of a vector space, this of course just corresponds to taking linear combinations of powers of a matrix, which is itself a matrix of the same dimension and therefore also an endomorphism.

Comment: I finally understood, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! This is a concept you'll perhaps see generalised to arbitrary modules over rings if you take further algebra courses...but is very important when working with just vector spaces.